# Mounting a new hard drive (sda1) to my existing filesystem

Tags: partitioning, mount

I tried to read some posts regarding mounting a new hard drive, but I am facing some problem. My new hard drive is sda1. The output of sudo fdisk -l is:

```
sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 999.7 GB, 999653638144 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121534 cylinders, total 1952448512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00016485

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048  1935822847   967910400   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2      1935824894  1952446463     8310785    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5      1935824896  1952446463     8310784   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x78dbcdc1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048  1953521663   976759808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

What should be done to add this new sda1 hard drive on booting up? What should be added in the `/etc/fstab` file? I have not performed any partition on the new sda1 drive. I need help on how to proceed from scratch and can't afford to take any risk.
Please help!

Comment: Do you have a GUI?

Comment: What type will it be? ext4? ntfs?

Comment: Yes I do have a gui! I don't know if it should be ext4 or ntfs as well.

Comment: Don't forget to ping in a comment (@someone) ext4 is linux, ntfs is used by windows. should windows be able to read the disk?

Comment: @Jacob: No, I have not dual booted the machine, so only have Ubuntu running on my box.

Answer (score 0):

A possible recommendation, which will mount **sda1** at system startup with read-write permissions for you and your group, and read-only permissions for others, might be adding this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=<ID-NO-OF-SDA1>   /media/<Your-User-Name>/<Label-Of-SDA1>   ntfs   defaults,auto,nls=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=002,fmask=113   0   0
```

And if you don't have any plans for a shared use of this drive with Windows, you can prefer using EXT4 format and then add this line instead:

```
UUID=<ID-NO-OF-SDA1>   /media/<Your-User-Name>/<Label-Of-SDA1>   ext4   nodev,nosuid   0   2
```

*Note: You can get the UUID and Label of SDA1 using GParted.*

Comment: No need to enter any command to mount?

Comment: I have important data that I would not like to lose, also I have an existing NFS mount, which got unmounted the last time I tried something like this!

Comment: The command `mount` is entered in Terminal, `fstab` entries like this is another way achieving the same result. AFAIK mounting partitions in this way, i.e. via `fstab` entries (especially using UUIDs instead of Labels) should not normally interfere with each other, and should not cause any data loss other than gaining full or restricted or no access to this or that device. In any case you might also use Clonezilla to backup a partition in a matter of minutes before trying.

Comment: Why ntfs? Like Jacob suggested above, should it be ext4?

Comment: @shank22 : 1) I assumed that you're happy with the existing format of **sda1** and would not want to re-format it unless you have a good reason to do so, in which case you should of course use other options for **fstab**, 2) the existing NTFS format of your **sda1** might be more convenient if you intend to use this disk drive from a non-Linux operating system like Windows now or in the future. Otherwise you can of course prefer EXT4 format and  perhaps just stick with the **defaults** in the **fstab** options.